# Camera App displays just a blank screen instead of video preview

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avfoundation

I'm trying to create a simple camera app for iOS using Xcode, SwiftUI, and AVFoundation. The code below builds successfully on a physical iPhone and I can see the small green light turn on indicating that the app has gained access to my iPhone's camera. However, instead of seeing the video camera feed as a preview on the iPhone screen, the screen is entirely white / black (depending on if dark mode is on or off).

I'm using an iPhone 12 Pro Max with iOS 16.5 installed. I've granted permission for the app to use the camera in Privacy & Security. The normal iPhone camera app works fine. I'm using Xcode 14.3 and there are no errors during build and launch. Console simply says "Camera access authorized"

Any idea why I can't see the video preview feed? Any insight would be much appreciated!

```
// OpenAI's minimum code for camera preview

import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let cameraView = UIView()

        guard let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video),
              let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
        else {
            return cameraView
        }

        captureSession.addInput(input)

        let photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
        captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput)

        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        previewLayer.frame = cameraView.layer.bounds
        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            self.captureSession.startRunning()
        }

        return cameraView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        // No need to update the preview layer in this case
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CameraPreview()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the screen of the iPhone to display a live video feed of the iPhones default camera, like it does for the regular camera app.

I tried restarting the iPhone, updating to the latest iOS, revoking camera permissions for the app and then reinstating them. Checked with ChatGPT and did everything it suggested except resetting all my permissions of my iPhone. I tried adding a string value to CFBundleDisplayName in Info.plist. I also tried adding AVCapturePhotoOutput()in the code above, but still no dice.

Comment: Thanks Klangfarb — do I need this to generate a preview?  Right now all the code has is AVCapturePhotoOutput()